# JavaScript random item from an imported array behaving strangely

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

The following code seems to be behaving strangely.  Basically, I'm importing a list of line-separated sentences from a text file, then making an array out of them.  But when I try to choose a random sentence from the array, it doesn't work because sentenceString becomes undefined.

However, when I run 
Math.floor(Math.random() * (sentenceArr.length) + 1);
I get a nice random number as expected.

And when I run sentenceArr.length
I get the number 12, which is indeed the length.

What am I missing?

```
    var sentenceArr = [];

    $.get('sentences.txt', function(data){
        sentenceArr = data.split('\n');
    });

    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sentenceArr.length) + 1);

    var sentenceString = sentenceArr[rand];

    var sentence = sentenceString.split(' ');
```

Update:
I tried making a Promise as suggested below, but it still doesn't seem to be working.  My new code with the Promise looks like this:

```
    var sentenceArr = [];
    var done = false;

    function loadSentences() {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sentenceArr.length) + 1);
        var sentenceString = sentenceArr[rand];
        var sentence = sentenceString.split(' ');
    };

    $.get('/sentences.txt', function(data){
        sentenceArr = data.split('\n');
        done = true;
    });     

    var isItDone = new Promise(function(resolve) {
        if(done) {  
            resolve('it worked');
        }   
    });

    //consume the promise:
    var checkIfDone = function() {
        isItDone
            .then(function (fulfilled) {
                loadSentences();        
            })

            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('oops, it failed');
            });
    };

    checkIfDone();
```

This seems to always return "oops, it failed", as if the promise is never fulfilled.  However, when I check the value of "done", it is "true", meaning the Ajax request was completed before moving on to the next steps.  Could anyone enlighten me?  I've read three tutorials on promises already, and can't seem to figure out my error in applying the concept to my own code.  Thank you.

Comment: Whats the generated random number? Is it in 0-11 range?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to manipulate the file content before the response of server be complete.

Take a look at promises to understand more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

And the way to solve your question using jquery ajax api.

```
var sentenceArr = [];
var file = 'path/to/file';

$.get(file)
.done(function (data) {
  sentenceArr = data.split('\n');
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sentenceArr.length) + 1);
  var sentenceString = sentenceArr[rand];
  var sentence = sentenceString.split(' ');

  console.log(sentenceArr)
  console.log(rand)
  console.log(sentenceString)
  console.log(sentence)
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code but it's still returning sentence as "undefined".  I also read up on promises (thank you for the link), and made one like so:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I solved the issue by first wrapping everything in a function, and using .then() to run everything only after the Ajax "get" was completed:

```
var sentenceArr = [];
```

const getData = () =>
        $.get('http://eslquiz.net/wordmix/sentences.txt', function(data){

```
    })

.then(data => {   // use this format to run function only after json get is done (since it's async)
                  // "data" is the contents of the text file
    sentenceArr = data.split('\n');
    console.log('Made sentence array');

    loadSentences();
```

});